# DataBinding - RecyclerView.ViewHolder throws error when trying to apply DataBindingUtil.inflate

Tags: android

I have a layout file in which an ImageView is located. I provided this with a `dataBinding`
. Within my adapter(ImageSliderAdapter) I am now trying to apply my view to the ViewHolder in the class for the ViewHolder called `ImageSliderViewHolder`. However, I get an error. How can I rewrite the code so that I can return and use the `sliderImageBinding` within the `onCreateViewHolder` function?

```
class ImageSliderAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageSliderAdapter.ImageSliderViewHolder>(){


private lateinit var sliderImages: ArrayList<String>
private lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater

fun ImageSliderAdapter(sliderImages: ArrayList<String>) {
    this.sliderImages = sliderImages
}


class ImageSliderViewHolder(view: ItemContainerSliderImageBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private lateinit var itemContainerSliderImageBinding: ItemContainerSliderImageBinding

    fun ImageSliderViewHolder(itemContainerSliderImageBinding: ItemContainerSliderImageBinding) {
        this.itemContainerSliderImageBinding = itemContainerSliderImageBinding

    }

    fun bindSliderImage(imageUrl: String) {
        itemContainerSliderImageBinding.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageSliderViewHolder {

    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    }
    val sliderImageBinding: ItemContainerSliderImageBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        layoutInflater, R.layout.item_container_slider_image, parent, false
    )

    return ImageSliderViewHolder(sliderImageBinding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageSliderViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindSliderImage(sliderImages[position])
}


 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return sliderImages.size
 }
}
```

item_container_slider_image.xml:

> 

```
<data>

 <variable
        name="imageUrl"
        type="String" />
</data>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="Store"
    android:imageUrl="@{imageUrl}"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop">

</ImageView>
```